# potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'v' used in boost isomorphism.hpp

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to boost and I was trying to use the isomorphism.hpp file for directed graphs.

while trying to run the code, in the boost library file I am seeing the error

> 1>c:\boost_1_55_0\boost\graph\isomorphism.hpp(142): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'v' used
>
> 1>c:\boost_1_55_0\boost\graph\isomorphism.hpp(147): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'v' used

It is being thrown from here,

```
BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(v, G1, Graph1){

    f[v] = graph_traits<Graph2>::null_vertex();  //error thrown here
}
```

This is defined in boost/graphs/iteration_macros.hpp as seen below:

```
#define BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(VNAME, GNAME, GraphType) \
for (std::pair<typename boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertex_iterator, \
               typename boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertex_iterator> BGL_RANGE(__LINE__) = vertices(GNAME); \
  BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) != BGL_LAST(__LINE__); BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) = BGL_LAST(__LINE__)) \
  for (typename boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertex_descriptor VNAME; \
    BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) != BGL_LAST(__LINE__) ? (VNAME = *BGL_FIRST(__LINE__), true):false; \
     ++BGL_FIRST(__LINE__))
```

Where do we need to define this? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1>c:\boost_1_55_0\boost\graph\isomorphism.hpp(142): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'v' used

Given...

```
BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(v, G1, Graph1)
```

...and...

```
#define BGL_FORALL_VERTICES_T(VNAME, GNAME, GraphType)
```

...we know `v` is known as VNAME within the macro.

The condition on the outer loop is:

```
BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) != BGL_LAST(__LINE__)
```

The condition on the inner loop is:

```
BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) != BGL_LAST(__LINE__) ? (VNAME = *BGL_FIRST(__LINE__), true):false;
```

Given the inner loop doesn't run unless the outer loop condition is satisfied, we can simplify:

```
true                                      ? (VNAME = *BGL_FIRST(__LINE__), true):false;

                                            (VNAME = *BGL_FIRST(__LINE__), true)      ;
```

Clearly VNAME is always assigned to and never used uninitialised.  Your compiler's analysis is flawed, and you should disable the warning (only for this specific code if at all possible), otherwise turn off any treat-warnings-as-errors compiler option so your build doesn't break completely or try another compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Project > "ProjectName" Properties > C/C++ > General
```

There you should switch "SDL checks" from `Yes` to `No`.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 (platform toolset v142) with C++20 enabled and warning level 4 gives a lot of warnings. To silence them:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4244) // '-=': conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
#pragma warning(disable: 4267) // '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
#pragma warning(disable: 4456) // declaration of 'xxx' hides previous local declaration
#pragma warning(disable: 4701) // potentially uninitialized local variable 'xxx' used
#pragma warning(disable: 4703) // potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'xxx' used
#include <boost/graph/isomorphism.hpp>
#pragma warning(pop)
```